# Testing an async function within a promise using jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, unit-testing, jestjs

I have a piece of code I have been struggling to test. It is a promise, and within that promise is another async function. For example:

```
export const myFunc = () =>
   new Promise ((resolve, reject) =>
     anAsyncFun()
       .then(response => axios.post(response))
       .then(response => doSomething(response))
       .catch(err)
  )
```

How do I tell jest to return a specific value from 'anAsyncFunc()' and pass that value onto the next step of the function.
Here is the actual function

```
    export const refreshAuth = () =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
    getRefreshToken()
      .then(refreshJWT =>
        axios.post(`${BlindlyApi.auth}/refresh`, {
          refreshJWT
        })
      )
      .then((res: AxiosResponse<JWTData>) => {
        onSignIn(res.data.accessJWT, res.data.refreshJWT);
        resolve(res.data.accessJWT);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.error('failed to refresh the access token', err);
        reject(err);
      })
  );
```

And here is what I have for testing right now.

```
    import axios from 'axios';
// import * as SecureStore from 'expo-secure-store';
import * as OAuth2 from './OAuth2';

const mockedAxios = axios as jest.Mocked<typeof axios>;
jest.mock('axios');

describe('OAuth2', () => {
  it('posts data to back end and handles the response correctly', async () => {
    const data = {
      data: {
        accessJWT: 'token',
        refreshJWT: 'refresh'
      }
    };
    const SecureStore = require('expo-secure-store');
    const mockGetItemAsync = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue({ refreshToken: 'refresh' });
    SecureStore.getItemAsync = mockGetItemAsync;

    mockedAxios.post.mockImplementationOnce(() => Promise.resolve(data));
    return OAuth2.refreshAuth().then(res => expect(res).toEqual(data));
    // expect(refreshAuth()).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    // expect(mockGetItemAsync).toHaveBeenCalledWith('refresh');
  });
});
```

Right now it catches the error, saying it cannot read data of undefined.

Comment: please add your jest code

Comment: Added it above @AkashDathan

Comment: It looks like your mock of axios is not correct. I think res is undefined instead of being an object

Comment: Yes @Axnyff, I am unsure of how to correctly mock this. I need to mock the first function getRefreshToken(), then I need to mock the return value of the post, then I need to mock the return of the signIn.